# How to properly declare a friend of a nested class of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, warnings

When I do the following:

```
template <typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    class Iterator
    {
        friend bool operator==(const Iterator& x, const Iterator& y);
    };
};
```

gcc gives me the following warning and suggestion:

```
warning: friend declaration 
'bool operator==(const Container<T>::Iterator&, 
                 const Container<T>::Iterator&)' 
declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]

friend bool operator==(const Iterator& x, const Iterator& y);
                                                           ^

(if this is not what you intended, 
 make sure the function template has already been declared 
 and add <> after the function name here)
```

I am fairly sure that this is a new warning, since I have always done it like this and never had any problems.

Can someone please explain why is this a warning, and what it warns about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's warning about the fact that it is going to be virtually impossible to define that `operator==` out-of-class.

That is to say, that `friend` declaration befriends a non-template `operator==` function - for example, `Container<Int>::Iterator` has as a friend the function

```
bool operator==(const Container<Int>::Iterator&, const Container<Int>::Iterator&);
```

This function is *not* a template, so there's pretty much no way to define `operator==` for all possible `Container`s outside the class template definition.

If you try to do

```
template<class T>
bool operator==(const Container<T>::Iterator&, const Container<T>::Iterator&);
```

That's a function template, and doesn't match the friend declaration. (In this case it's even worse, as you can't actually use this operator because `T` is in a non-deduced context.)

The warning message suggests one possible fix - first declaring a function template and then befriending a specialization of it. (You'll need to pull `Iterator` out of the class into its own separate class template so that `T` can be deduced.) The other possible fix is to just define the function inside the class template definition.

Answer (score 4):

The declaration

```
friend bool operator==(const Iterator& x, const Iterator& y);
```

declares a *non-template* function at the nearest enclosing namespace scope which takes two arguments of type `const typename Container<T>::Iterator&`. Thus, every time the class `Container` is instantiated, with some template parameter `T`, a new *overload* of `operator==` is declared.

Since this `operator==` is not instantiated from a template, you cannot define it out-of-line as a template. So the only way to define this `operator==` you have declared is to define it separately for each type for which `Container` is instantiated. This is almost certainly not desirable.

The warning warns you that the friend you declared is not a template, which has the undesirable consequences I just explained.

I believe the correct way to do what you are trying to do is the following:

```
template <typename T>
class Container_Iterator;

template <typename T> bool operator==(const Container_Iterator<T>& x,
                                      const Container_Iterator<T>& y);

template <typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    typedef Container_Iterator<T> Iterator;
};

template <typename T>
class Container_Iterator {
  friend bool operator==<T>(const Container_Iterator<T>& x,
                            const Container_Iterator<T>& y);
};

// btw, don't forget to define operator==
```

Now we explicitly declare `operator==` as a template, and each specialization of the iterator declares the corresponding specialization of `operator==` as its friend.

Comment: I just asked the very similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986937/c-friends-in-template-classes-separation-of-interface-and-implementation?noredirect=1#comment55730416_33986937

so you might be able to help me as well. You say "So the only way to define this operator== you have declared is to define it separately for each type for which Container is instantiated." which is exactly what I want to do. Do you know how this would work in my case?

Comment: @Mario You just define a non-template function with the correct signature for the types you want. But as I say, you need to do this separately for every type. I really think you don't want to do this.